# Indicating a space in Groovy Property

Tags: csv, groovy

I'm new to Groovy. I am using the Groovy CSV parser to read in some data, but have run into an issue because some of the CSV file headers have spaces.  Is there a way to specify a space character in a Groovy property?  Example:

```
def csv = new File("data.csv").text
def data = new CsvParser().parse(csv)
for(line in data) {
println "$line.First Name $line.Last Name"
}
```

CSV:

```
Last Name, First Name
Smith,John
Jones,Sally
```

This fails due to the extra space characters.  (Yes, I could change the CSV file, but that's a last resort.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
println "${line.'First Name'} ${line.'Last Name'}"
```

Or, an alternative syntax:

```
println "${line[ 'First Name' ]} ${line[ 'Last Name' ]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [] method to look up the property:

```
"${line['First Name']}
```

Comment: As in my answer, you'd need to wrap that in `{}` to get it to parse